# Symfony Check if user is still online

Tags: php, symfony, session

I know that this question was asked multiple times in Stackoverflow, but i don't actually know how to get it work.
So i found in the other threads that i could perform an Ajax call every 5 minutes for exemple and update at each call the `lasttimeseen` (or whatever) column in the database.
But how to perform this Ajax call. I know how to perform it from JS on every page visit , but this will result in a big load of requests. i want to schedule the call. A piece of code would be a good help, if possible.

I also thought of creating an action in a controller, and call this action every 5 minutes. But again i don't know how to schedule the action call.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var _lasttimeseen = setInterval(lasttimeseen, 30000);

function lasttimeseen() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('route_to_update_lasttimeseen') }}",
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        success: function (msg) {}
        ...
        })
}
```

Something like this is helping you ?

Comment: It does. didn't know that setInterval exists. Thank you so much, i will implement it and get back to you